# MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away

Tags: mysql

I'm a server at my office to process some files and report the results to a remote MySQL server.

The files processing takes sometime and the process dies halfway through with the **error: 2006, mysql server has gone away**

Ive heard about the MySQL setting, **wait_timeout**, but do I need to change that on the server at my office or the remote MySQL server?

Answer (score 0):

> do I need to change that on the server at my office or the remote
>   MySQL server?

If it die while processsing, this error is thrown by the MySQL server at your office. Otherwise, dying after the process completed means that the remote MySQL server throw this error.

In your case, I suspect that you're sending a too large query to the remote MySQL server. You can increase the query limit by setting [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) variable.

Take a look at the [document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) for the common causes of this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu server.

I tried changing the max_allowed_packet and the wait_timeout settings but neither of them fixed it.

It turns out that my server was out of RAM. I added a [1GB swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) and that fixed my problem.

Check your memory with `free -h` to see if that's what's causing it.